# How to display image in modal for each marker on Google Maps API map

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple markers on the map and click on every marker displays infowindow with some specific data for that marker. Additionally there would be an anchor tag to open a modal pop-up in which I would place image for that marker.

My controller:

```
public function welcomePage() {
    $problems = Problem::with('problemImages')->get();

    return view('welcomePage')
            ->with('problems', $problems)
}
```

My welcomePage.blade.php:

```
var map;
function initAutocomplete() {
    const centerMap = {lat: 48.3767994, lng: 17.5835082};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: centerMap,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
    displayMarkers();
}

function displayMarkers() {
    @foreach($problems as $problem)
         var loc = split(" {{ $problem->location }}");
         createMarker(getLocVar(loc[0], loc[1]), map, "{{$problem->id}}");
    @endforeach
}

function createMarker(location, map, id) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map,
            });

    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: "<p>" + "<b>ID: </b>" + id + "</p>"
         + "<a data-target='#myModal' data-toggle='modal'>Show image</a>"
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function () {
         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function split(str) {
    return str.split(",");
}

function getLocVar(lat, lng) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
}
```

Each `$problem` have image field which I can access like `$problem->problemImages[0]['name_of_the_file']`. All the images are stored in storage folder which has symlink to public folder. One solution would be to pass id of the problem into ajax call and with controller return name of the image for that problem that i could load in modal. But I can't figure it out on my own. As you can tell I am trying to learn javascript and php in laravel so any help would be really appreciated. Sorry for my english aswell. If you have any questions I can provide you with more detailed information.

Comment: I would suggest not doing a PHP loop within your Javascript function. Instead use `var problems = @json($problems);`. The `@json` directive makes your data into a format that can be used in Javascript directly. And if images are in the `public` folder, you don't need ajax, just set the icon to the image URL?

Answer (score 0):

Set your image path  `icon: image path`

```
function createMarker(location, map, id) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map,
                icon: set your image path to this,
            });
```

Comment: I didn't ask my question very clearly for that I am sorry. I don't want to set icon image for that marker. I just want to have a link in infowindow that opens modal with image for that problem. Each problem have stored image in database.